# Catching events after calling the FileSystem.FileCopy UI dialog

Tags: vb.net, dialog, file-copying

I copy some files to some destination and in the meantime I want to log the file names in a text file.

I'd like to use the Windows 7 Copy/Replace dialog in the case the files are already present in the destination folder (to keep users in a "known" environment).

But my problem is that I am not able to catch the 4 different events depending on the user's choice :

- Replace
- Do not copy
- Copy with a different name
- Cancel (for this one I can throw an exception and catch it)

  ```
      Dim oFile As New StreamWriter(strTextFile)
      For Each p In Me.Files ' List of custom class with file information like Path, Extension, etc...
          Dim strFileName = Path.Combine(strDestinationFolder, p.FileName)
          If File.Exists(strFileName) Then
              Try
                  My.Computer.FileSystem.CopyFile(p.Path, strFileName, UIOption.AllDialogs, UICancelOption.ThrowException)
              Catch ex As Exception
                  ' I would like to catch user's choices here to react accordingly in the text file
              End Try
          Else
              oFile.WriteLine(p.Path & ";" & p.FileName)
          End If
      Next
      oFile.Close()
  ```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can't, the dialog takes care of it.  You need to re-think this.

Comment: The logic behind is not difficult at all so it will not be a problem to create my own Copy/Replace form. But it is a pity I can not use the integrated one (for layout purpose). Thx.